# after HTTP request via Groovy i have list of maps I need to add a new list to each element

Tags: list, groovy, jmeter, jsr223

After one HTTP Get on some request I create a list of maps with ids which looks like this

```
for (i=0; i<response.data.size(); i++){
    def tempMap = [:];
    tempMap['id'] = response.id[i];
    tempMap['name'] = response.name[i];
    listOfMaps.add(tempMap);
}

listOfMaps=[[id:1, name:123], [id:2, name:456]]
```

Then I do a GET HTTP request using that id to get list of versions like this:

```
def myVerList = parser.parseText(response)
println(myVerList);

[[version:1.0.0, createdAt:Mon Jul 15 2019 15:51:48 GMT+0200], [version:2.0.1, createdAt:Mon Jul 15 2019 15:25:48 GMT+0200], [version:2.0.0, createdAt:Mon Jul 15 2019 14:51:48 GMT+0200], [version:1.3.0, createdAt:Mon Jul 15 2019 13:51:48 GMT+0200], [version:1.1.0, createdAt:Mon Jul 8 2019 18:22:48 GMT+0200]]
```

I need to add this new list to the given id above.

final result should look like this:

```
[

[id:1, name:123],  [[version:1.0.0, createdAt:Mon Jul 15 2019 15:51:48 GMT+0200], [version:2.0.1, createdAt:Mon Jul 15 2019 15:25:48 GMT+0200], [version:2.0.0, createdAt:Mon Jul 15 2019 14:51:48 GMT+0200], [version:1.3.0, createdAt:Mon Jul 15 2019 13:51:48 GMT+0200], [version:1.1.0, createdAt:Mon Jul 8 2019 18:22:48 GMT+0200]]], 

[id:2, name:456],  [[version:2.0.0, createdAt:Mon Jul 15 2019 15:51:48 GMT+0200], [version:2.0.1, createdAt:Mon Jul 15 2019 15:25:48 GMT+0200], [version:2.0.0, createdAt:Mon Jul 15 2019 14:51:48 GMT+0200], [version:1.3.0, createdAt:Mon Jul 15 2019 13:51:48 GMT+0200], [version:1.1.0, createdAt:Mon Jul 8 2019 18:22:48 GMT+0200]]

]
```

How do I problematically in Groovy inside my JSR232 post processor?

I tried this it works but it has duplicate data

```
def response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
def myJson = parser.parseText(response)

for(item in listOfMaps){
    if (item["id"] == vars.get("thatId")) {  item["versions"]=myJson;   }
        newList.add(item)
}

vars.putObject("newList",newList);
```

The only thing is newList has two sets of entries

Comment: Is the closing `]` intentionally not after `name:123`?

Comment: sorry it was a copy and paste thing it should be there, I was trying to hid personal stuff and missed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compare integers:

```
if (item["id"] == Integer.parseInt(vars.get("thatId"))) {
```